# SSRS Report executes directly but WCF ReportExporter.Export method returns null Result and no errors

Tags: wcf, reporting-services

I have a report that is hosted in SQL Server 2012 SSRS and it executes fine through the browser. I am trying to run it using WCF as a Service Reference for the SSRS 2005 asmx from a ASP.Net web project and return it as a PDF using the `ReportExporter.Export()` method; however, it is not returning a result at all and the warnings array is empty.  So, how can I troubleshoot the process to see where the difficulty is?  I did not find any errors in the SSRS Log file even when I set it to verbose; nor did I find any errors in the standard SQL Log.

Here is my code:

NOTE: the call `ReportExporter.Export(..)` is to a  method that encapsulates the execution of the webServiceProxy to the Service Reference.

```
{ 
    IList<SSRS_Reports.ParameterValue> parameters = new List<SSRS_Reports.ParameterValue>();
    parameters.Add(new SSRS_Reports.ParameterValue { Name = "paramId", Value = _paramId.ToString() }); }

    byte[] result = null;

    string extension = string.Empty;
    string mimeType = string.Empty;
    string encoding = string.Empty;
    string reportName = "/baseFolder/ReceiptReport";

    SSRS_Reports.Warning[] warnings = null;

    string[] streamIDs = null;
    string uN = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rptUName"].ToString();
    string uP = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rptPWD"].ToString();
    string uD = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rptDomain"].ToString();

    //NOTE: the call "ReportExporter.Export(..) is to a  method that encapsulates the execution of the webServiceProxy to the Service Reference.
   ReportExporter.Export("ReportExecutionServiceSoap",
                         new System.Net.NetworkCredential(uN, uP, uD),
                         reportName,
                         parameters.ToArray(),
                         ExportFormat.PDF,
                         out result,
                         out extension,
                         out mimeType,
                         out encoding,
                         out warnings,
                         out streamIDs);

   if (result != null)
   {
       //create a file and then show in browser
       _mPDFFile = randomName() + ".pdf";
       _mPDFPath = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "\\pdf\\" + _mPDFFile;

       //clear files older than today
       Lib.FileManager.ManageFiles(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "\\pdf", "*.pdf", -1);

       if (File.Exists(_mPDFPath)) 
       { 
           File.Delete(_mPDFPath);
       }

       FileStream stream = File.Create(_mPDFPath, result.Length);
       stream.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
       stream.Close();

       return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I definitely don't have the answer to your question, but what is your method declaration?  From your return value it looks like it's only returning a bool, not a report type object.  Additionally, not all code paths return a value, so I would think this wouldn't even compile.

Comment: True, this is not the whole method so if you try to do a compile with it you will get an error.  This is just the code section that is pertinent. I actually have the identical code in a different project that is running in production and rendering a report just fine; so, the problem I am having here is particular to this report.